# Views contextual filter to a number of product variations

Tags: commerce, views

I am having real trouble with this and would appreciate any help.

I have a view block that needs to display all variations of a product that have the same sku with an increment at the end.

Example:

Product name is: 4 jembi avenue

This produces a url of /4jembiavenue

All product variation skus are based on this, so every product variation will now have sku

4jembiavenue0
4jembiavenue1
4jembiavenue2

so on so forth.

What I need is views to display ALL product variations in the view.

I can achieve this by using a filter and setting it to Contains: 4jembiavenue. However as I am intending to have many products displayed like this I do not want to do it like this as each new product would have to have a new block and a new view.

I can use a contextual filter to get the value (4jembiavenue) from the URL and it works fine, but of course it only displays 1 product variation where I am going to need up to 60.

So my question is this:

How can I use a contextual filter with a "contains" operator to find and display all of the product variations?

If you know of any other way I can achieve this I would gladly try this too.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try like. First include sku in your view and exclude it from display. Then write this code it would give u desired results.

```
function modulename_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
    {
    if($view->name=='yourname'){
        preg_match('/.*[^\d+]/',drupal_get_path_alias(),$match);
        $query->add_where(1,'commerce_product.sku','%'.$match[0].'%','LIKE');
    }
}
```